# Is it possible to send an email by a Gmail alias through Outlook 2013?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have successfully set-up several mail forwards for my personal website through Gmail. The email server at the address forwards to @ and Gmail can send as these addresses (having done the simple verification step required).

I also know you can set up Outlook 2013 to send as Gmail by creating a new account and setting the correct POP settings etc.

Does anyone know if it is possible to send an email through Outlook that will have the correct alias when sending as Gmail? Instead of it always sending as the gmail account regardless of selected alias.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. This seems more on topic here than over at WebApps as it is through the desktop Outlook application.

Answer (score 2):

Outlook 2013 has gotten much better about replying with the correct FROM. When you create a new e-mail address, the default FROM will be the e-mail box that is currently highlighted.

Below is an example where I can select between my work and personal e-mail address. I had to use Outlook.com for personal since our corporate firewall blocks all IMAP and POP3 (including Gmail).

Anyway, you can also change the FROM (via a drop down) any time:

[image: FROM]

Comment: Sadly I've tried that and it still appears as <myuser>@gmail.com regardless of what I select in the FROM box.

Comment: @TomWilkinson You would need to set up those other e-mails separately in Outlook. I hear it is a clusterf*ck to set up, but it can be done. Outlook doesn't have a way to send using a specific FROM unless you've added that e-mail account. This is one of the many frustrations I share with you between Outlook and Gmail. I use Outlook because I have to for work, not because it is a superior product.

Comment: @TomWilkinson You would need to set up those other e-mails separately in Outlook. Outlook doesn't have a way to send using a specific FROM unless you've added that e-mail account. Haven't figure out the part about just sending email but not receiving.

Answer (score 1):

SO basically what you have to do is to configure Gmail alias first (just note for newbies) - https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370

Also you need to have Gmail account configured in Outlook - mine is **IMAP**, IDK if it would work with POP3.

I'm receiving all of my emails on one gmail account, so I just had to deal with sending - **WITHOUT ADDING ANOTHER ACCOUNT.**

1. Get FROM option without having to add second account
2. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type `regedit` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Registry path is based on MS Office version e.g.[OfficeVersions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcRB2.png)
4. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Preferences`
5. Add new DWORD key called `ShowFrom` with hexadecimal value = `00000001`
6. Log Out/ Log in
7. Open Outlook
8. When composing new msg,you should now have `FROM` option available
9. Just enter email address you have alias of on gmail, it will remember this address for next time use
10. All the magic is handled by Gmail

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do it is use the alias email when you are setting it up and use the actual gmail account email as the login.